# Removing html image tags and everything in between from a string

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I've seen a number of questions about removing HTML tags from strings, but I'm still a bit unclear on how my specific case should be handled.

I've seen that many posts advise against using regular expressions to handle HTML, but I suspect my case may warrant judicious circumvention of this rule.

I'm trying to parse PDF files and I've successfully managed to convert each page from my sample PDF file into a string of UTF-32 text.  When images appear, an HTML-style tag is inserted which contains the name and location of the image (which is saved elsewhere).

In a separate portion of my app, I need to get rid of these image tags.  Because we're *only* dealing with image tags, I suspect the use of a regex may be warranted.

My question is twofold:

1. Should I use a regex to remove these tags, or should I still use an HTML parsing module such as BeautifulSoup?
2. Which regex or BeautifulSoup construct should I use?  In other words, how should I code this?

For clarity, the tags are structured as `<img src="/path/to/file"/>`

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any other HTML in this file? Or is it literally nothing but plain text and `<img>` tags?

Comment: @senderle No, there is no HTML besides the <img> tags, hence my hesitance in using a full-fledged HTML lib.  The format is *always* how I describe it above.

Comment: I just posted an answer, but was wondering, is there actually an apostrophe after the closing > of every image, or was that a typo?

Comment: @joshcartme  Good catch!  That was indeed a typo!

Comment: Alright cool, I was going to update the answer I posted below to handle apostrophes =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would vote that in your case it is acceptable to use a regular expression.  Something like this should work:

```
def remove_html_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)
```

I found that snippet here (http://love-python.blogspot.com/2008/07/strip-html-tags-using-python.html)

edit: version which will only remove things of the form `<img .... />`:

```
def remove_img_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<img.*?/>')
    return p.sub('', data)
```

Comment: I saw that page earlier, too, but I'm a bit confused about the regex in question (note that I know *nothing* about regex use).  Why the `.*?` string?  Shouldn't it read something like `<img src*>` ?

Comment: The way the first one I posted worked was to remove anything between < and >.  If you you had other instances of < or > in your plaintext (not as html tags) it would have removed stuff it shouldn't have.  I just posted another version which is a bit more selective.

Comment: Just another quick question.  I should have mentioned that the strings I'm trying to free of <img> tags are UTF-32 bytestrings.  Is there anything special I have to do in order for this to work?  I don't seem to be detecting any <img> tags...

Comment: Adding '?' after '*' makes it not greedy.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about the UTF-32 bytestrings.  So it just isn't working at all?

Answer (score 3):

Since this text contains *only* image tags, it's probably OK to use a regex. But for anything else you're probably better off using a bonafide HTML parser. Fortunately Python provides one! This is pretty bare-bones -- to be fully functional, this would have to handle a lot more corner cases. (Most notably, XHTML-style empty tags (ending with a slash `<... />`) aren't handled correctly here.)

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> 
>>> class TagDropper(HTMLParser):
...     def __init__(self, tags_to_drop, *args, **kwargs):
...         HTMLParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
...     self._text = []
...         self._tags_to_drop = set(tags_to_drop)
...     def clear_text(self):
...         self._text = []
...     def get_text(self):
...         return ''.join(self._text)
...     def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
...         if tag not in self._tags_to_drop:
...             self._text.append(self.get_starttag_text())
...     def handle_endtag(self, tag):
...         self._text.append('</{0}>'.format(tag))
...     def handle_data(self, data):
...         self._text.append(data)
... 
>>> td = TagDropper([])
>>> td.feed('A line of text\nA line of text with an <img url="foo"> tag\nAnother line of text with a <br> tag\n')
>>> print td.get_text()
A line of text
A line of text with an <img url="foo"> tag
Another line of text with a <br> tag
```

And to drop `img` tags...

```
>>> td = TagDropper(['img'])
>>> td.feed('A line of text\nA line of text with an <img url="foo"> tag\nAnother line of text with a <br> tag\n')
>>> print td.get_text()
A line of text
A line of text with an  tag
Another line of text with a <br> tag
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  I think I'll go the regex route for now because it seems to involve less code (simplify, simplify!).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
def remove_HTML_tag(tag, string):
    string = re.sub(r"<\b(" + tag + r")\b[^>]*>", r"", string)
    return re.sub(r"<\/\b(" + tag + r")\b[^>]*>", r"", string)
```